# git pipeline fails with error: needs to match exactly one accessor! (when .gitlab_ci.yml calls a template from another repo)

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab, devops

I am trying to get my gitlab pipeline to call a pipeline template from another repo. Pipeline fails with the following error:

By the way, pipeline succeeds if remove reference to external repo and instead refer to the file in calling repo locally). gitlab-ci-template.yml file exist both in the calling repo and in the called repo.

**ERROR:**

```
Found errors in your .gitlab-ci.yml:
Include `{"file":"/gitlab_ci_template.yml"}` needs to match exactly one accessor!
You can also test your .gitlab-ci.yml in CI Lint
```

**My .gitlabci.yml**

```
image:
  name: ubuntu:20.04
  entrypoint:
    - '/usr/bin/env'
    - 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'

include:
  - project: 'foocompany/sandbox/foo-sandbox/templates/pipelines/test_include_pipeline_source'
  - file: '/gitlab_ci_template.yml'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra "-" before "file". You don't need dash in that line.